# Parse Json File in NodeJS displays unexpected results in Node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the below nodejs code that reads contents of baseline.json file and parse it. I then try to display all the Computer ID and LastReportTime. I see an odd behaviour it would not print all the ID and LastReportTime. Also, the results are different every time i run it. The json is big for me to upload here so i uploaded on Json Blob.

Nodejs Code

```
var fs = require('fs');

try {
    var json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('baseline.json'));
    for (var obj in json) {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty(obj)) {
            console.log(obj);
            console.log("\n \n");

            if (obj == "BESAPI") {

                for (var prop in json[obj]) {
                    console.log(prop);
                    if (prop == "Computer") {
                        // loop over Computer dataseries
                        for (var id in json[obj][prop]) {
                            console.log(prop + ':' + json[obj][prop][id].ID);
                            console.log(prop + ':' + json[obj][prop][id].LastReportTime);
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }

} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

Raw JSON

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f27f75879e48c5387a03

Comment: could you post a few lines from `baseline.json` instead? Also: output from the script might help, too.

Comment: @amenthes I uploaded the raw json to https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f27f75879e48c5387a03

Comment: You could at least pretty print the JSON :-/

Answer (score 0):

In your posted array, LastReportTime and ID are arrays.

Try these lines:

```
console.log(prop + ':' + json[obj][prop][id].ID[0]);
console.log(prop + ':' + json[obj][prop][id].LastReportTime[0]);
```

Comment: When i run it only prints 143 ID's however there are a total of 177 ID's in the JSON. I am not sure why it ignores the rest.

Comment: I ran it again this time it printed 146 ID's ... any idea whats wrong ?

Comment: No idea, but do all of the IDs fall under `BESAPI` and `Computer`?

Comment: Yes they do, i was deploying this app on Cloud Platform with NodeJS runtime. I tried it on my local linux machine now and i can retrieve all ID's. It is so weird.

Comment: @user3846091: If this answer didn't solve the problem, you should not accept it. It will be confusing to future visitors. It seems like the root problem is not with the code you posted. You should investigate and post your own answer or delete the question. But as it is right now it gives the impression that if you concatenate a string with an array instead of the first elements, JS doesn't iterate over all rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you pretty print you can see the data comes in two flavors, the top portion followed by the balance of the data in a standard form which does repeat 177 times

```
{
    BESAPI: {
        $: {
            xmlns:xsi: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation: "BESAPI.xsd"
        },
        Computer: [
            {
                $: {
                    Resource: "api/computer/2431038"
                },
                LastReportTime: [
                    "Thu, 26 Feb 2015 14:54:41 +0000"
                ],
                ID: [
                    "2431038"
                ]
            },
            {
                $: {
                    Resource: "api/computer/16710075"
                },
                LastReportTime: [
                    "Thu, 26 Feb 2015 14:45:18 +0000"
                ],
                ID: [
                    "16710075"
                ]
            },
            {
                $: {
                    Resource: "api/computer/3415985"
                },
                LastReportTime: [
                    "Thu, 26 Feb 2015 14:50:52 +0000"
                ],
                ID: [
                    "3415985"
                ]
            },
            {
                $: {
                    Resource: "api/computer/11736335"
                },
                LastReportTime: [
                    "Thu, 26 Feb 2015 14:54:41 +0000"
                ],
                ID: [
                    "11736335"
                ]
            },
```

I am chopping out many lines her, but it ends normally as

```
            {
                $: {
                    Resource: "api/computer/5520740"
                },
                LastReportTime: [
                    "Thu, 12 Feb 2015 02:49:11 +0000"
                ],
                ID: [
                    "5520740"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Using nodejs [you can pretty print using](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-object-pretty-print) :

```
var pretty_print = require('js-object-pretty-print').pretty;


var parsed_data = JSON.parse(data_from_file);

console.log(pretty_print(parsed_data)); // good pretty print
```